# Set value in a column on click of a button in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have a customized form in SharePoint 2013. I want that on click of the submit button on the list, a value will also update.

Currently on click of the submit button, it is saving the values and redirecting to the home page.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="btnFormAction" 
 onclick="javascript:{
    ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={https://homepage.aspx}')
 }"
 style="width: 119px" />
```

I have created one flag with default value as 0, I want once the user click on the submit button this flag value will change to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick` from the button and write an `onclick` event in jQuery like `$('input[name="btnFormAction"]').click(function(){})` and use REST api / JSOM to update the value to the list. Here you can also redirect to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are in a SharePoint FORM, so when you add a button the click event is bubbling up to the FORM, and the FORM is submitted.

You have to add JavaScript code to stop that from happing with

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

or

```
event.preventDefault();
```

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

*mark the answers as answered to keep StackExchange clean*

Comment: This also means that the onclick is never executed and he'll have to handle the saving himself.

Comment: the onclick *is* executed but not propagated (if I have to be symantically correct). So call the saving function after you have executed your own stuff. The same is done in your jQuery solution